# Express $f(\theta)=6\cos2\theta+5(\sin2\theta)^2+3$ as a sum of powers of $\sin\theta$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

Please explain how to express the below formula as a sum of powers of $\sin \theta$

$$f(\theta)=6\cos2\theta+5(\sin2\theta)^2+3$$

Comment: [double angle formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Double-angle.2C_triple-angle.2C_and_half-angle_formulae)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $$\cos(2\theta)=\cos^{2}(\theta)-\sin^{2}(\theta)=1-2\sin^{2}(\theta)$$ and $$\sin^{2}(2\theta)=4\sin^{2}(\theta)\cos^{2}(\theta)=4\sin^{2}(\theta)(1-\sin^{2}(\theta)).$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** First convert from $\sin 2\theta$ to $\cos 2\theta$ by using the identity:

> $$
> \sin^2 2\theta+\cos^2 2\theta=1
> $$

Then convert from $\cos 2\theta$ to $\sin \theta$ by using the identity:

> $$
> \cos 2\theta = 1-2\sin^2 \theta
> $$